# XSLT 2.0 Filter out element where all attributes are blank

Tags: xslt

I'm looking to do a simple filter that ignores elements whose attributes are all blank. I can look at each attribute individually:

`<xsl:if test="@abc ne '' or @def ne '' ... >`

But I think it would be more elegant to just look at all of them at once. This seems close but doesn't work:

`<xsl:if test="count(@*[not(matches(., ''))]) ne 0">`

Any suggestions on how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Correction: it does seem to work, but maybe there's more elegant code to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might prefer a readable expression:

```
every $atr in @* satisfies $atr eq ''
```

or even:

```
every $atr in @* satisfies not(string($atr))
```

If you prefer something shorter, then perhaps:

```
not(@*!='')
```

---

P.S. Consider using a [predicate](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath20-20101214/#id-predicates) instead of `xsl:if`.